# Remove special character from JSON data by JOLT processor

Tags: json, special-characters, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I have following json input . The Input contain many special character I want to remove all the special character form the input data

**Expected Input**

```json
{
    "A": "pwnbfd%2hdj&mdnb",
    "B": "my name is param (India) ",
    "C": "@pqwe",
    "D": "jfdk@djnsn(america) djhfb "
}
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
    "A": "pwnbfd2hdjmdnb",
    "B": "my name is param India",
    "C": "pqwe",
    "D": "jfdkdjnsnamerica djhfb"
}
```

I need the above changes by using jolt transform json processor in apache nifi. There could be many other keywords in json payload.
I need to remove all the special characters from the input json so please help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know(*furthermore* don't think) whether there's a straightforward method to remove all of them, but you can individually remove each desired character within a **modify** transformation by using successive ***split*** and ***join*** functions like this :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('%',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('&',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('@',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('\\)',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=split('\\(',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```